# Activate SQL statements logging with Hibernate and Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA repository using Hibernate as provider. I would like to log SQL statements but I can't achieve that. I tried various solutions :

- Set showSql to true in my HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
- Add log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG to my log4j.properties file (it's worth mentioning that log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO did add some logging information but log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG didn't)

Here are my classes and configuration files:

**DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
/**
 * Database configuration
 *
 * @author dupirefr
 */
@Configuration
@Import({BaseConfiguration.class, DatabaseProperties.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = DatabaseConfiguration.REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    /*
     * Constants
     */
    public static final String MODEL_PACKAGE = "be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.model";
    public static final String REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE = "be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.repositories";

    /*
     * Beans
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(DatabaseProperties properties) {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(properties.url);
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.username);
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.password);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.driverClassName);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(MODEL_PACKAGE);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

}
```

**database.properties**

```
# Data source
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

**DatabaseProperties.java**

```
/**
 * Database properties
 *
 * @author dupirefr
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:be/dupirefr/examples/spring/batch/simple/config/database/database.properties")
public class DatabaseProperties {

    /*
     * Fields
     */
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    public String url;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    public String username;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    public String password;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    public String driverClassName;

}
```

**EmployerRepository.java**

```
/**
 * {@link Employer}'s repository
 *
 * @author dupirefr
 */
@Repository
public interface EmployerRepository extends JpaRepository<Employer, Long> {

}
```

**EmployerRepositoryIT.java**

```
/**
 * {@link EmployerRepository}'s integration test
 *
 * @author dupirefr
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DatabaseConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
public class EmployerRepositoryIT {

    /*
     * Constants
     */
    public static final Employer GOOGLE = new Employer(1L, "Google");
    public static final Employer MICROSOFT = new Employer(2L, "Microsoft");
    public static final Employer APPLE = new Employer(3L, "Apple");

    /*
     * Fields
     */
    @Autowired
    private EmployerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /*
     * Setups
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        entityManager.persist(GOOGLE);
        entityManager.persist(MICROSOFT);
    }

    /*
     * Tests
     */
    @Test
    public void findById_Exists() {
        assertEquals(GOOGLE, repository.findById(GOOGLE.getId()).get());
        assertEquals(MICROSOFT, repository.findById(MICROSOFT.getId()).get());
    }

    @Test
    public void findById_NotExists() {
        assertFalse(repository.findById(Long.MAX_VALUE).isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(GOOGLE, MICROSOFT), repository.findAll());
    }

    @Test
    public void save() {
        repository.save(APPLE);
        assertEquals(APPLE, entityManager.find(Employer.class, APPLE.getId()));
    }

    @Test
    public void delete() {
        repository.delete(MICROSOFT);
        assertNull(entityManager.find(Employer.class, MICROSOFT.getId()));
    }

}
```

**log4j.properties**

```
# Appenders
## Console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Loggers
## Root
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

## Hibernate
### Generic
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
### SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Why is it that the previous solutions didn't work ? Is there some kind of incompatibility between Spring Data JPA and Hibernate SQL logging configuration ?

EDIT :
I tried both solutions proposed in comments but none of them worked. I also tried to change the database I was using (H2 for HSQL) or to specify Hibernate dialect but that didn't work. As a matter of fact Hibernate dialect is automatically found for some databases when using Spring.

EDIT 2 :
I tried to change logging level of the rootLogger to TRACE. I also try to specify a threshold for the appender explicitely. And finally I tried to add JpaProperties with showSql = true but none of them did the trick. I think that there is something really obvious to do that I'm missing to unlock the complete situation :-/

EDIT 3 :
Calling the logger directly as in the following test did work. I became to wonder if there is a typo or something that prevent Hibernate to use the logger.

```
@Test
public void delete() {
    LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL").debug("delete()");
    repository.delete(MICROSOFT);
    assertNull(entityManager.find(Employer.class, MICROSOFT.getId()));
}
```

Here are the resulting logs:

```
10:33:45,158  INFO DefaultTestContextBootstrapper:257 - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
10:33:45,183  INFO DefaultTestContextBootstrapper:206 - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
10:33:45,185  INFO DefaultTestContextBootstrapper:184 - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1f28c152, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7d907bac, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@7791a895, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@3a5ed7a6, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@6325a3ee]10:33:45,376  INFO GenericApplicationContext:589 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4493d195: startup date [Sun Jan 14 10:33:45 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:46,187  WARN ConfigurationClassEnhancer:353 - @Bean method BaseConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
10:33:46,448  INFO DriverManagerDataSource:133 - Loaded JDBC driver: org.h2.Driver
10:33:46,743  INFO LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:361 - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:33:46,798  INFO LogHelper:31 - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
10:33:46,922  INFO Version:45 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
10:33:46,924  INFO Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:33:46,979  INFO Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
10:33:47,318  INFO Dialect:157 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
10:33:48,472  INFO LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:393 - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
10:33:49,422  INFO TransactionContext:105 - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@2e3f79a2 testClass = EmployerRepositoryIT, testInstance = be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.repositories.EmployerRepositoryIT@1460c81d, testMethod = delete@EmployerRepositoryIT, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@38b5f25 testClass = EmployerRepositoryIT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.config.database.DatabaseConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager@5b22b970]; rollback [true]
10:33:49,468 DEBUG SQL:83 - delete()
10:33:49,512  INFO TransactionContext:137 - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@2e3f79a2 testClass = EmployerRepositoryIT, testInstance = be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.repositories.EmployerRepositoryIT@1460c81d, testMethod = delete@EmployerRepositoryIT, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@38b5f25 testClass = EmployerRepositoryIT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class be.dupirefr.examples.spring.batch.simple.config.database.DatabaseConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]].
10:33:49,516  INFO GenericApplicationContext:989 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@4493d195: startup date [Sun Jan 14 10:33:45 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
10:33:49,519  INFO LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:571 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

EDIT 3:
I finally figured out what happen. I noticed that on failed tests SQL queries were issued in the logs. And by tuning a little bit my log4j properties I saw they came from hibernate logger, as expected.

But successful operations were not issuing logs. And that's because they don't reach the database. Everything happens within the entity manager and so no SQL is needed. Now I know that I just have a problem with my H2 database that I need to figure out.

Comment: Try by adding  `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` in the porperties file and see?

Comment: You said that `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO` added some logging but `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` didn't. Did you try... `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG`? Or is there a typo above?

Comment: @AhmedRaaj : Those properties must go in a Spring properties file (like application.properties). I don't have any, I'm not using Spring Boot. I tried to add log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=‌​TRACE to my log4j.properties file but as this logger's goal is to display binded parameters it had no effect.

Comment: @dimwittedanimal : No typo there :-). I mentioned log4j.logger.org.hibernate to point out the fact that it had an effect on loggings, though the other one had not (which I find weird). I tried to set DEBUG level to the former logger though and it displayed more information but still no queries (as it's not its job that was expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since looking at the code you provided doesn't seem to cut it, I'll try it with some instructions how to debug this.

1. Leave the changes as given in my 1st answer in place.
2. Make sure the properties file you showed is actually controlling the logger configuration. For this change, for example, the output format and check that it affects the output as expected.
3. Find a relevant logging statement in Hibernate. Put a breakpoint there. Debug until you find the place where the log statement gets discarded. Compare the data structures involved with your configuration to learn what is going wrong.

Comment: I'll try that :-). I didn't mention it before but setting logging level of rootLogger to TRACE did add some logs, but not the SQL queries.

Comment: I tried to put a breakpoint of the first line of my test and get the org.hibernate.SQL logger there. It seems well configured.

I'll still try to get a logging statement in hibernate classes but it's not as easy as it seems :-)

Comment: I didn't had time to dig further, and I still have no solution. But given the amount of help you've given me I decided to award you the bounty for this question :-)

Comment: I finally figured out what happen. I noticed that on failed tests SQL queries were issued in the logs. And by tuning a little bit my log4j properties I saw they came from hibernate logger, as expected.

But successful operations were not issuing logs. And that's because they don't reach the database. Everything happens within the entity manager and so no SQL is needed. Now i know that I just have a problem with my H2 database that I need to figure out.

Thanks a lot again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

With

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout
```

And possibly add

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=TRACE
```

If you want the values of bind variables as well.

You had your logging configured fine, but your appender was only picking up `INFO` and SQL statements are logged on `DEBUG`

Comment: That seems indeed legit :-). I'll try that tonight and come back to you with the result!

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. Thinking about it that was expected as it only changes the logging level of the root logger and not the threshold of the appender (which I also tried to change by the way but didn't work either).

Thanks for the try though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the threshold of the appender. The appender doesn't have one, except through its configuration for the root logger.

Comment: There is a threshold parameter for appenders, independent from loggers logging level. It allows log to be different from an appender to another without having to change loggers logging level. For example if you want to log everything in the console but only errors in a file you can configure your appenders with different threshold while not touching your loggers configuration.

Comment: Ok, got it now.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

private Properties properties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    return properties;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I had a similar config class as yours, since I am update to spring boot I removed that class and moved all the config to the application.properties file. My config is:

```
#DataSource
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456

#Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Comment: You have a few things more than I have (dialect or session context), but are those connected to the problem? Dialect is not, it's automatically found by Spring (and I tried to specify it explicitly just in case, changed nothing).